# A light rendering problem or an export problem?

Tags: rendering, export, color-management

I'm encountering a problem, as usual I tried to make it smaller and smaller until I would reach a point where it becomes clear what I've done wrong and after repairing that I rebuild.

But now I run into something I actually don't understand well enough. Let me start from the beginning:

I trying to create an object with Blender that is suitable for use on a 3D-printer. At one point I loose the color I've put via the lamp. Attached the Blender-file stripped of all unnecessary things down to the point I think is the core problem.

What I did basically:

- Used Blender v.2.77a, platform Mac OS X;
- Started with the default cube, fresh reload;
- I set the screen layout to scripting (because I use it later on)
- Next I open up a new window, set this to *UV/Image-editor*;
- In the *3D-View*, I selected the default cube, go into edit mode, select all;
- Then I unwrap the default cube, I used the *Smart UV Project*, this shows a map (unwrap) of the cube;
- In the *UV-Editor* window I choose image, opened the image (prepared before in Photoshop, a sixfold copy of the same image, saved as Hazel2Cube.png);
- In the *3D-view* in *Viewport Shading* I select the *Texture* option
- To light the object I've placed six area lamps, each parallel to one of the sides. I used a very small python script for this, `licht-basis.py`, go to the editor window open file `licht-basis.py` and run it via the run script button (once). When I project white light here (RGB colors 1, 1, 1) this shows as a crisp and clear object. I can export this cube to a Wavefront .OBJ file, open it in another program (e.g. MeshLab) and it looks good;
- This can be seen in file: `cube-problem-1.blend`;
- And I can export it to a wavefront file, see files: `cube-problem-1.obj` and `cube-problem-1.mtl`

The cube shows with the selected image on all sides, just open the attached .blend file to see this. So far, so good.

Problems:

1. Now I change the scene by changing the color of the six area lights, I  change the `varycolor` parameter to `True` (last line in the editor window and immediately I see the result, but exporting this does NOT show these additional colors, the system uses the Blender and built-in Texture rendering by default. This can be seen in file: `cube-problem-2.blend`, after exporting to a second set of files and comparing the files `cube-problem-1.obj` and `cube-problem-2.obj` only differ in the name and referencing to the .mtl-files. It seems that the color of the light is left out when exporting.

So is this an exporting problem or something that goes wrong in the render?

2. Trying to use a more explicit render, I tried both the Blender and the Cycles, used viewport shading to rendering, they start, run for a few seconds (7?) and show "Done". In the 3D-view I see the lamp colors (although faintly, but they are there) But no image. Saving it in .obj shows the image again without the lamp colors, identical to the other files.

What am I doing wrong here?

How can I combine an image with other colors like the lamps here?

Files:

```
cube-problem-1.blend
cube-problem-2.blend
Hazel2Cube.png
licht-basis.py
cube-problem-1.obj
cube-problem-1.mtl
cube-problem-2.obj
cube-problem-2.mtl
PROBLEM.txt     - this text
```

(I tried to attach all files, but failed in doing that...)

Thanks for at least reading this!

Regards,
Wim.

Comment: Your question relies mainly on inspecting a file, but there is no file for us to see? Post then some images or anything that might help us understand the issue.

Comment: I tried to upload, but the web-site doesn't let me do that....

Comment: Find a site that can host the file, and paste the link as part of your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the OBJ file format does not support any type of lighting information. It simply saves geometry, simple materials, and links to image textures (via the .mtl file).

I think perhaps your first example with the white lights is misleading you, as I don't think you're actually seeing the surfaces lit by the lights in the other 3d app, you're just seeing the image textures shown on the surfaces?

Comment: Hi @Todd, thanks for reply'ing. I didn't know OBJ doesn't supports lightning information. But it is also consistent with the render run I did, that also doesn't show lightning info.

Comment: Next test: I removed some of the lamps, the sides of the cube involved then turn black immediately in Blender. Of course. But exporting to OBJ similar show the image texture on all sides. That proves the same effect, no light is also not processed/saved.

Comment: So is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you need to stick with OBJ, then I think you'll have to create a new set of tinted image textures. You might be able to get a transferable material using FBX, but not sure how reliable export from Blender is. It also seems to support lamp objects, so maybe try that.